# Analytic Function Derived From Recursive Reverse Taylor Series?

Tags: recurrence-relations, taylor-expansion

Given the following recursive relation:

$a_0 = 1,$
$a_n = a_{n-1}(p-2q)+2(-p)^n$

is there a simple function that has this as its Taylor series,
i.e.

$f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{a_n}{n!}x^n$

where $f$ is something (relatively) simple?

Note: This function is derived from $f(x) = (pe^{-px} - qe^{(p-2q)x})/(p-q)$,
which surprisingly has no variables $p$ or $q$ in its denominator.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand the question since you give the answer. Could you clarify ?

Comment: I am asking whether there is a function, not written as a power series, that has my power series as its Taylor series. For example, $a_0=1$, $a_n=a_{n-1}(p-2q)$ are the coefficients for the function $e^{(p-2q)x}$. It's just that this recursion is more challenging!